# Windows service - MSBUILD

Tags: msbuild, windows-services

I have a MSBUILD script used with my application factory in order to stop the Windows Service if it runs, then wait for a while and copy/paste the bin files.

Here is a part of my script :

```
<Message Text="Stopping Service" Importance="high" 
    Condition="$(%(Server.Identity)ServiceExists) == true" />
<ServiceController MachineName="%(Server.Identity)" ServiceName="$(ServiceName)" Action="Stop" 
    Condition="$(%(Server.Identity)ServiceExists) == true" />
<Sleep Seconds="60" Condition="$(%(Server.Identity)ServiceExists) == true" />
```

But even if my windows service is initially stopped, we are still doing this operation. What is wront in this condition : `Condition="$(%(Server.Identity)ServiceExists) == true"` ?

Comment: Because it only checks if the service is installed, not it's state.

Comment: And what is the condition for the running value ? Is there any documentation ?

Comment: [MSBuildTasks Documentation ServiceQuery](https://github.com/loresoft/msbuildtasks/blob/master/Documentation/TaskDocs.md#ServiceQuery) is what you're looking for.